# Condition Formatting with Value Error via applying function on dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, boolean, conditional-statements

I am trying to create some conditions to filter 2 columns in the my datasheet.

```
 def Bull_Bear(Percent_from_high,Percent_from_low):
    if (Percent_from_low > 0.01) & (Percent_from_high < 0.001):
        return True
    elif (Percent_from_high > 0.010) & (Percent_from_low< 0.001):
        return False
    else:
        return 'N/A'
```

So i am trying to create a new column to return either True/False or N/A given the conditions and here is what i wrote:

```
df['Bull_Bear'] = df.apply(lambda x :Bull_Bear(df['Percent_from_high'],df['Percent_from_low']))
```

I am returned this error:

> ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index Date')

Any idea what I did wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This is a vectorized solution to the problem, which will run better on large datasets.

Create dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Percent_from_high": np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(50,)),
        "Percent_from_low": np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(50,)),
    }
)
```

Add a new column with np.nan.

```
df["Bull_Bear"] = np.nan
```

Create two sets of masks.

```
mask1a = df["Percent_from_low"] > 0.01
mask1b = df["Percent_from_high"] < 0.001
mask2a = df["Percent_from_high"] > 0.01
mask2b = df["Percent_from_low"] < 0.001
```

Assign values when filtred.

```
df.loc[mask1a & mask1b, "Bull_Bear"] = True
df.loc[mask2a & mask2b, "Bull_Bear"] = False
```

Result:

```
print(df.head(10))
```

```
   Percent_from_high  Percent_from_low Bull_Bear
0             0.9743           -0.7118     False
1             0.1564            0.1861       NaN
2             0.9408            0.3726       NaN
3            -0.7476            0.6435      True
4             0.4863           -0.7650     False
5             0.7512           -0.2044     False
6            -0.7848            0.5729      True
7            -0.6985           -0.3628       NaN
8             0.1579           -0.7709     False
9            -0.2554           -0.7636       NaN
```